# How can I prevent a redirect loop using SSL with gunicorn/nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-middleware

I get a redirect loop when using SSL middleware to redirect certain urls to HTTPS. What should I do?

My nginx config is set up to forward requests to gunicorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of steps here.

First of all, modify the way your middleware checks for SSL:

```
  def _is_secure(self, request):
    if request.is_secure():
      return True

    if 'HTTP_X_SSL_PROTOCOL' in request.META:
      return True

    return False
```

Then change your nginx config as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ...

    location / {

        ...
        proxy_set_header X-SSL-Protocol $ssl_protocol;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
}
```

`proxy_set_header` will only be passed on if `ssl_protocol` is not null, i.e., it's a secure connection.

Restart nginx and you're done.

Comment: Since django 1.4, you don't need a custom middleware as it is built-in. See also [SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header). Nice trick for nginx by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tom's answer.  If you are behind Heroku or other load balancer, the following might help also.

```
def _is_secure(self, request):
    if request.is_secure():
      return True

    if 'HTTP_X_SSL_PROTOCOL' in request.META:
      return True

    # check the forwarded request's protocol
    if request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO')=='https':
        return True

    return False
```